# ARIA read revealed text on click

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria, voiceover

I'm working on HTML code that creates "spoiler blur." The idea is that we want to include information in the text, a "spoiler," that some people may not want to read.

The text should appear blurred, to protect the viewer from reading it accidentally, but if the user clicks the text, the text should unblur to become clear.

Consider this code sample.

```js
const spoiler = document.querySelector("#spoiler");
spoiler.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    spoiler.classList.remove("spoiler");
    spoiler.removeAttribute("role");
    spoiler.removeAttribute("aria-label");
})
```

```css
.spoiler {
    filter: blur(0.5em);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Star wars spoiler</p>
<div id="spoiler" class="spoiler" role="button"
  aria-live="assertive" aria-label="reveal spoiler">
  Vader is Luke's father.
</div>
```

It works perfectly for sighted users, and it *almost* works for users of ARIA screen readers, but not quite.

When I test this with iOS Voiceover, I can navigate to the spoiler text, and the screen reader announces the text as a button, saying, "reveal spoiler," without reading the spoiler text "Vader is Luke's father." So far, so good.

Then, when I double-tap to activate the button, the text unblurs.

Expected: When I activate the button in Voiceover, the screen reader should announce the change, and read the spoiler text, "Vader is Luke's father."

Actual: When I activate the button in Voiceover, the screen reader says nothing. When I tap the text again, *then* it reads the text, "Vader is Luke's father."

How do I convince the screen reader to read the spoiler text right away after the user activates the button?

Comment: I’m currently looking into this, but the first thing I notice is that the spoiler-reveal is not keyboard usable, so inaccessible for most screen reader users… Or did you remove the tabindex? How do you actually navigate to the button?

Answer (score 0):

Changing attributes and DOM structure necessary to calculate an accessible name is a bit risky, screen readers and browsers might not recalculate at the moment you are expecting.

I do not have VoiceOver, so this is a shot in the dark. The demo below does the following:

- Keep `aria-label` but change it’s value to the element’s text
- Focus the element once again, just to be sure

One of those might solve the issue, it would be great if you could test it and share your results.

```js
const spoiler = document.querySelector("#spoiler");

const reveal = () => {
    spoiler.classList.remove("spoiler");
    spoiler.removeAttribute("role");
    spoiler.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
    spoiler.setAttribute("aria-label", spoiler.textContent);
    spoiler.focus(); // just an experiment
};

spoiler.addEventListener("click", reveal);
spoiler.addEventListener("keydown", e => [" ", "Enter"].includes(e.key) && reveal());
```

```css
.spoiler .spoiler-text {
    filter: blur(0.5em);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Star wars spoiler</p>
<div id="spoiler" class="spoiler" role="button" tabindex="0"
  aria-live="assertive" aria-label="reveal spoiler">
  <span class="spoiler-text">Vader is Luke's father.</span>
</div>
```

There are some more things here that I changed:

In your example code the very important `tabindex="0"` and a keyboard handler are missing, which are fundamental to screen reader accessibility. But your test description makes me assume you covered that in your tests.

Since the *focus indicator* must always be visible, the demo is only blurring the contents of the button.

You are removing the button role­—which might be confusing to screen reader users by itself—but then the element should not be focusable any more (what role should it have, otherwise?). So I’m using `tabindex="-1"` to be able to focus it in JavaScript, but not by means of the keyboard.